# ASP.NET MVC - Bypass Login and use Windows Username to Authenticate User and Authorize Sections with their Stored DB Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created an asp.net mvc web application and added a login using this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/Asp-Net-mvc-5-security-and-creating-user-role/

The application is working, and I was able to add the content and add in authorization to different pages with the roles in the database assigned to the users registered to the application.

Now, a request has come in to allow users to authenticate using their System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and the role I have stored in the database. I will add that the application is only accessible to internal employees, but I still want to be able to register the employee (as I am the admin) with the appropriate role.

I have tried different things like:

- a custom authorize attribute:

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute()

    {
        myRoleController = new MyRoleController();
        this.allowedroles = myRoleController.GetRoleNames();
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorize = false;
        var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
        var userId = user.Id;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var userRole = myRoleController.GetRoleNameByUserId(user.Id);
                foreach (var role in allowedroles)
                {
                    if (role.role == userRole) return true;
                }
            }


        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
           new RouteValueDictionary
           {
                { "controller", "Home" },
                { "action", "UnAuthorized" }
           });
    }
```

- I added the custom authorize with the role to the different sections
- I changed authentication mode to Windows in Web.config
- I tried adding the custom authorize attribute to the FilterConfig.cs
- I setup the IIS on the server to allow Windows Authentication

, but it still asks for the login.

I don't know what else to try to essentially not require the login anymore, but use the windows user name and my stored roles to authenticate and then view the different website sessions.

Part of the Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
      <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" />
      <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound/" />
      </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageNotFound" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you also please share your config file?

Comment: Have you ensured if anonymous authentication is disabled.

Comment: Under Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Security I have Request Filtering and Windows Authentication (Installed) checked, but I don't see anonymous

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right-click your project, click Properties, click the Web tab, make sure that "Anonymous Authentication" is set to "Disabled".

Comment: On the site in the IIS manager, I clicked on Authentication and I see Anonymous and Windows are both enabled. I don't see it as an option on the web tab inside Visual Studio Code 2022.

Comment: Can you make Anonymous as disabled in IIS manager and try.

Comment: With Anonymous disabled, it is still not working.

Comment: Ok, one last try - Ensure that the user's Windows account has the necessary permissions: The user's Windows account needs to have the necessary permissions to access your application and its resources (such as the database). Make sure that the user is a member of the appropriate Windows group or has been granted the necessary permissions directly.